# How to handle REST API Use Case of POST Request dependent on a Job

Tags: rest, web-api-testing

A POST request creates some data .A Job runs once in every 48 hrs and send email of successfully resource created.
How to test it? We dont want to wait for 48 hours after POST request?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible answers here

1. Change the system clock after the POST has run to force the job to run right away.
2. Change the schedule in your test environment so that the job runs more frequently
3. Add hooks to run the job "on demand" so that you don't have to wait on the schedule
4. Test your app in smaller pieces.  This often means designing your app so that it *can* be tested in smaller pieces, making "testing requirements" first class design constraints.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain more on point 3 and 4 can be implemented